# 入力された数字が小数点第2位かどうか判定

Tags: python

pythonのプログラミングで、Aテーブルに入った売場面積のデータが小数点第2位以上だったら、「小数点第2位までで入力してください」というログを残したいのですが、
どのように書けばよいでしょうか。

Comment: 「テーブルからデータを読み取る」「データが小数点第2位以下かを判定する」「ログに出力する」など、いくつかの手順に分けることができますが、分からないのはどの部分でしょうか？(もしくは全部？)

Answer (score 0):

「有効数字が小数点第2位まであるかどうかで分岐をする」と読み替えて回答します。

正規表現を使い、以下のように実現可能です。

```py
import re

def main():
    pattern = re.compile(r'^[0-b9]+\.[0-9]{2}$')
    for test_str in [
            'not a number',
            '100',
            '100.1',
            '100.12',
            '100.123',
    ]:
        if re.match(pattern, test_str):
            print("OK", test_str)
        else:
            print("NG", test_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```